# relationship between token ID, smart contract and JPG image

Tags: nft

I want to know if it is possible in an NFT to separate the image (e.g. jpg of an artwork) from the underlying relationship between the token ID and the smart contracts. Since only the underlying metadata is hosted on blockchain, while the jpg image is hosted on external storage.
Is it an indestructible link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on implementation, nothing stops you from updating the uri link later if your contract allows it.

The way it work usually you have a onlyOwner setter function to update metadata storage link, usually on ipfs. On the other hand if you want it to remain there forever you can hardcode it into the contract before deploy.